# How to add command/button to Maya AETemplate?

Tags: maya, editortemplates

I'm trying to integrate a simulator into Maya. I have a solver node. I would like to put a button on the attribute editor, "Simulate" for example that calls a command. How can this be achieved with AETemplates and MEL?

Comment: Do you already have an AETemplate node for your solver node? If yes, show what your already tried.

Comment: I've got a normal template, it works, I've exposed my node attributes. It's a a normal template, exposing attributes like "editorTemplate -label "Timestep" -addControl "timestep"" for example. -addControl only adds attributes if they exist. I was thinking of using -callCustom, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Simply doing "button -label "simulate" -c command " adds a button at the top of the editor ignoring the editorTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at some templates which use extra elements like AEfileTemplate.mel.
You have to use the current parent to add the UI elements at the correct place.

```
string $oldParent = `setParent -q`;
setParent $parent;
```

Now you can continue creating your own UI layouts or buttons.